# BUG in Google Calendar iCAL / ICS export all day events?

Tags: calendar, export, google-calendar, ics, calendar.app

I set up a test calendar on Google calendar.
Following dates are marked:

```
For September
------------------------
all day events
17.09.2019 - 20.09.2019
27.09.2019 - 27.09.2019
------------------------

For October
------------------------
events with start/end time specified
17.10.2019 - 20.10.2019, from 12:00PM to 12:00PM
27.10.2019 - 27.10.2019, from 12:00PM to 12:00PM
------------------------

All dates are shown correctly in Google Calender front-end.

If I export the calender to ical / .ics file .. the all day events/dates differ from above! Events/dates with start/end time specified are shown correctly, why? And how can I fix that?

Google Calendar ics file shows ...

For September (wrong)
------------------------
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190917
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20190921 <- why September 21. must be 20.

DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190927
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20190928 <- why September 28. must be 27.


For October (correct)
------------------------
DTSTART:20191017T100000Z
DTEND:20191020T100000Z

DTSTART:20191027T110000Z
DTEND:20191027T113000Z
```

Answer (score 2):

The calendar is working correctly.  The DTEND field in ical is non-inclusive.

From html version of the iCal RFC on icalendar.org [1](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-6-1-event-component.html):

> The "DTSTART" property for a "VEVENT" specifies the inclusive start of
>   the event. For recurring events, it also specifies the very first
>   instance in the recurrence set. The "DTEND" property for a "VEVENT"
>   calendar component specifies the non-inclusive end of the event.

Meaning the DTEND fields is not included in the event.  In the case of the above example

> DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190917
>   DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20190921

The event spans the date 17-09-2019 to 20-09-2019 and does not include the date 21-09-2019.